# Как в Django генерировать slug url

Tags: python, django

Есть задача генерировать `slug`(при создании поста с помощью формы на сайте) в зависимости от `title` поста. К примеру:

```py
title = "собака"
```

значит

```py
url = "127.0.0.1:8000/sobaka"
```

Пытался использовать функцию `slugify`:

models.py:

```py
def gen_slug(string):
    finally_slug = slugify(string, allow_unicode=True)
    return finally_slug + '-' + str(int(time()))

class Post(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    post_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True, verbose_name='URL', null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.post_slug = gen_slug(self.post_title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('show_post', kwargs={'post_title_slug': self.post_slug})
```

urls.py:

```py
path('post/<slug:post_title_slug>/', ShowPost, name='show_post'),
```

views.py:

```py
def homepage(request):
    random_content_one = Post.objects.order_by("?")[:30]

    context = {
        'random_content_one': random_content_one,
    }
    return render(request, 'sitelogic/base.html', context=context)


def ShowPost(request, post_title_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, post_slug=post_title_slug)
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'title': post.post_title,
    }
    return render(request, 'sitelogic/showpost.html', context=context)
```

base.html:

```html
{% for random_thumbnail_one in random_content_one %}
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
    <a class="plink" href="{{ random_thumbnail_one.get_absolute_url }}">View</a>
  </button>
{% endfor %}
```

Работает только если `title` был заполнен английскими буквами. Если русскими то возникает ошибка. К примеру если `title = "собака"`, то ошибка будет такая:

```
NoReverseMatch at

Reverse for 'show_post' with keyword arguments '{'post_title_slug': 'собака-1672068769'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<post_title_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']
```

P.S: С уникальностью slug'ов проблем нет, т.к дополнительно используется модуль `time` при генерации url'ов

Comment: Если вы хотите не `собака`, а `sobaka`, значит уберите `allow_unicode=True`

Comment: Я пробовал этот вариант. Если allow_unicode=False, то тогда ссылка сгенерируется, но будет в таком виде: 127.0.0.1:8000/-1672068769. А надо 127.0.0.1:8000/sobaka-1672068769

Comment: А, тогда придётся искать какую-то другую библиотеку для транслитеризации русских букв (но какую конкретно посоветовать, не знаю)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо что указали в каком направлении стоит двигаться, ибо идей не было вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip uninstall slugify
pip install python-slugify
```

main.py

```
from slugify import slugify

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(slugify("собака"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но проблема уже решена. Кстати тоже благодаря slugify. Помечу ваш ответ за решение.

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека `transliterate`.

```
slug = slugify(transliterate (title, 'ru', reversed=True))
```